# Unable to run __main__() from intellij/pycharm - maybe issue with doctest?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm

In a module that has python facet enabled - and in which I am able to run - and even debug  - another python script, there is one file that can not be run.

There is a **main**() defined:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

This may have to do with doctests:  See the screenshot:

But in that case, I still just want to run the **main**.  That should be possible, no?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click inside the "if __name__ ..." block, the Python plugin will offer you the option to run the file directly.

Comment: .. or it will not.. That is the first procedure I attempted (and retried many times)